# HDPI / Retina vector layers in OpenLayers 3

Tags: openlayers, vector-layer, retina

I'm rendering some vector features on top of HDPI tiles. The tiles are crystal clear on my HDPI monitor but the vector features are blurry:

[image]

Is there a way to make the vector layer "retina" as well?

Answer (score 3):

I figured it out:

I was using the `image` attribute of `ol.style.Style` rather than setting the `geometry` attribute. For example, I did this:

```
new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
        radius: 5,
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: '#79FF33'}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 1}),
        snapToPixel: true
    }),
    zIndex: 1
})
```

When I should have been doing this:

```
new ol.style.Style({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Circle(feature.getGeometry().getCoordinates(), (resolution * 5)),
        fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: feature.get("timeColor")}),
        stroke: new ol.style.Stroke({color: 'black', width: 50}),
        zIndex: 1
})
```

Comment: Did the points remain scale independent? You have rendered the points as circles with 300 map units (I guess in your case meters) radii. I did not experiment with the `geometry` property of the style object yet, however it wouldn't be logical for me, if the points remained the same size on different scales.

Comment: I just discovered this issue. Nope. I'm going to have to find a different solution.

Comment: Updated post. Using a fixed number of units to represent the circle results in the circles increasing in size as the user zooms in. Instead, I simply multiply the resolution variable passed by `ol.style.StyleFunction` by the number of pixels I want the circle to take up: `(resolution * 5)`

Comment: Additionally, if you don't want the size flicker when zooming in or out, set `updateWhileAnimating: true` on the vector layer.

Comment: Sadly, I haven't found a way to similarly style `ol.geom.Multipoint` yet.